# Laravel multi db connection

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have database server where registrered my customers. Each customer has one database. After the login, I need to switch/change the db connection into CUSTOMER db connection. So I can't create in my database.php config one db connection for each customer. I tested Config::set(), but it works for only one request. I have used Eloquent.

Comment: If you have to switch connections per every request, it sounds like a design flaw

Comment: Use the `Config::set` on a Middleware and you'll have your routes connecting to the database you want on every request.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @Jaylen the question is: how can connect to "personal" customer DB dinamically? I can have 1000 customers and each of them have one db, in my login page I check if the customer holding exists, if true, I need to connect to his DB and work with his data.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu yes, but in the login I have three field: code_customer, username, password. Code_customer identify the customer so the DB (if customer exists), while username and password identify the user. So I need before to check if code_customer exists then I connect to DB customer and then check if user for that customer's DB exists.

Comment: If I create two connection string in my config/database.php, one connection is for my db server and the second is generic for the custoemrs, and I create a shared class where get db connection data, so I can change parameters in run-time. Is a correct solution?

Comment: Try this https://lukevers.com/2015/03/25/on-the-fly-database-connections-with-laravel-5